# sorcery occured error on rails4 on using mongoid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, sorcery

I wanna use sorcery gem using user authentication and mongid gem

add Gemfile to

gem 'sorcery'

$ bundle

$ rails g sorcery:install core reset_password

I was success using activerecord...

but mongoid not make defualt sorcery initial files..

why  not make initial files

help expert persons :(

```
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
/Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:126:in `included': Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern (ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks)
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sorcery-0.8.5/lib/sorcery.rb:73:in `block in <module:Sorcery>'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sorcery-0.8.5/lib/sorcery.rb:72:in `module_eval'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sorcery-0.8.5/lib/sorcery.rb:72:in `<module:Sorcery>'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sorcery-0.8.5/lib/sorcery.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/user_name/Desktop/rails/project/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Comment: `bundle binstub rails` did you run this also try `bundle exec rails g sorcery:install core reset_password`

Comment: @RajarshiDas It also occured same error......